# Improper gsub replacement

Tags: ruby

I am trying to replace all alphanumeric characters of an email with the '#' character using the `gsub` method but Ruby is inserting a backslash before the '@' character.

E.g:

`"john@doe.com".gsub(/[a-z0-9]/, "#")` returns `"###\#@###.###"` instead of `"####@###.###"`.

Comment: You can also use the `\w` metacharacter: `"john@doe.com".gsub(/\w/, "#")`

Comment: @orde `\w` and `[a-z0-9]` are different sets of characters.

Comment: Note that the backslash is not inserted before `@`, but before the `#` preceding `@`.

Comment: @mudasobwa: good point.  `\w` will match on uppercase letters and underscores.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It returns `"####@###.###"` as expected, try to:

```
puts "john@doe.com".gsub(/[a-z0-9]/, "#")
```

What you see in IRB/Pry is the prevention of `#@` being interpreted as string interpolation.

Please also refer to very valuable comment by @Stefan below.

Comment: More precisely the result of [`String#inspect`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/String.html#method-i-inspect). A `#` followed by `$`, `@`, or `{` will be escaped.

Answer (score 3):

`tr` is  faster than `gsub`:

```
puts "foo@bar.com".tr('a-zA-Z0-9', '#')
# >> ###@###.###
```